# Extract floats from string to create multiple/multidimensional arrays to manipulate data

Tags: python, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, floating-point

First off, I am very weak programmer, and new to python and this site. Sorry for my mistakes. So here goes, my data file looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/60E84azv

there are 6221 lines in total in the paste bin file. For testing, I limited the line numbers to a maximum of 1000.

I am trying to read in the float values in the number lines, with the main columns being 1 and 2.

So far i have written this code to extract the lines i want from the file:

```
f = open('Sample Data.txt',"r")

num=0
line = f.readlines()

for n in range (107, 1000, 1):  #6621

    if (n>108):
    print line[n]
```

which works pretty well, printing the numbers in each line as a string. (Each number has 4 spaces by which it is separated from the next, except the first number in each column which has 2 spaces.)

I now wish to convert the string into an array or list so that I can work with the individual numbers and eventually plot a graph with column 2 on the y axis. I've written the following to split and convert the string into floats:

```
for i in range(108,1000,1):
line[i].split('    ')
float(line[i]) = X[i]
print(X[i])
```

When I run this, it comes back with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 2, in <module>
print(X[i])
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

I've broken it down, and the line[i].split('    ') seems to kind of work, because when I test printed the line it gave 3 separate strings which look like:

```
['  5070.74537037   -0.003382', '0.009507\n']
```

I have no idea why there is this error. I thought X[i] was the new array that i was supposed to be creating with the floats but for some reason it doesn't seem to want to work. I've read somewhere that when using large data sets it's good to use multidimensional arrays... If I cannot even understand one dimensional, I have no chance at the other ones!

Is there any way I can create an array or maybe two one dimensional arrays which will allow me to manipulate the x or y column of the potential graph independently?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because you need to declared X as a list before the for loop:

```
X = list()
for i in range(108,1000,1):
   line[i].split('    ')
   float(line[i]) = X[i]
   print(X[i])
```

I think this will give the output you want:

```
f = open('Sample Data.txt',"r")
num=0
line = f.readlines()

    X = []
    for n, lines in enumerate(line, 0):  #6621
        # make it 109 to remove the first line "['# Column 3: Magnitude error\n']"
        if (n > 109): 
            linSplit = lines.split('    ')
            joined = ' '.join(linSplit)
            # apply the float function to every item in joined.split
            # create a new list of floats in tmp variable
            tmp = map((lambda x: float(x)), joined.split())
            X.append(tmp)


    print X[0] # print first element in the list
```

Output:
[5061.58148148, 0.079304, 0.011018]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Am I right in saying that the output is now a list containing string values? so if I wanted to convert say the 5061.58148148 value, I would just have to extract it from the string, convert it to a float and create a loop where this extraction is assigned to a new list such as hjd = []

Thank you once again!

Edit: it wont let me up vote, says I need 15 reputation :( if I could, I would.

Comment: No worries you will get your reputation up soon. You are right the output is a list of string values. I edited the answer to include a easy way of creating a list of floats instead, by using the `map` function. Or you could do what you said.

Comment: Thank you :). So to follow up, I have the list, and extracted the periods from the sample data. I have now written this block of code which should perform the following function.
    
    Period_1 = 0.870329
    Epoch_1 = 5062.4719
    phase = []
    j=0

    for j in range(0, len(X),1):
        phase_var = ((X[j][0] - Epoch_1)/Period_1)
        phase[j] = phase_var
        
    print phase[0]

Essentially producing a new list which should contain the phased X values (phase []) so I can plot them against the magnitude column.

Comment: Just realized I can add the function to the original post. Sorry. In addition to the last comment, when I try to run the script it comes up the error listed above. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have declared the list, and there is no need for me to initalize the list size either I don't think

Comment: you forgot to declare `X = list()` at the top. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled much more elegantly using `split` without any arguments for each line:

```
f = open('Sample Data.txt',"r")
num = 0
for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
    if (line_number < 109):
        #jump over lines at the beginning
        continue
    # now split the line everywhere there are one or more whitespaces:
    numbers_as_strings = line.split()
    # and convert the numbers to floats
    numbers = list(map(float, numbers_as_strings))
```

Comment: What does using `re` get you here over simply doing `line.split()`?  There's also no need to call `.readlines()`; `enumerate(f)` works just as well.

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks for the heads up. I didn't know that `split()` with no arguments would do all this for me. I've updated my answer to include your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring x before calling it in your for loop, if you declare it within your for loop, it will reinitiate with the initial value each loop passing. Try this.

`x = []

for i in range(108,1000,1):

    line[i].split('    ')

    x.append(float(line[i]))

    print(x[i])`

Comment: Thank you, I went back and declared the variable, but when I tried to print the list, it would print anything. No error message or anything, it would simply move on to a new ">>>" line. Sorry for my bad terminology.